# 3D multidimensional array output not matching initialization data

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been working on a code segment that flattens a 3D dimensional array, however I've encountered a rather baffling situation with the following code.

The array used is initialized as follows:

```
int array[][][] = {
            {
                {000, 001, 002},
                {010, 011, 012},
                {020, 021, 022},
            },
            {
                {100, 101, 102},
                {110, 111, 112},
                {120, 121, 122},
            },
            {
                {200, 201, 202},
                {210, 211, 212},
                {220, 221, 222},
            }
    };
```

And then outputting the array through a basic nested for loop.
The output is formatted through a custom DecimalFormat that allows me to print the floating 0's.

```
DecimalFormat xFormat = new DecimalFormat("000");


for(int z = 0; z < array[0].length; z++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < array[1].length; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < array[2].length; x++) {
                System.out.println("I = "+ i + " Element at i = " + xFormat.format(array[z][y][x]));
            }
        }
    }
```

This loop is used immediately after the initialization of the array, yet the output is what completely baffles me

```
I = 0 Element at i = 000
I = 1 Element at i = 001
I = 2 Element at i = 002
I = 3 Element at i = 008 <------- =/= 010
I = 4 Element at i = 009 <------- =/= 011
I = 5 Element at i = 010 <------- =/= 012
I = 6 Element at i = 016 <------- =/= 020
I = 7 Element at i = 017 <------- =/= 021
I = 8 Element at i = 018 <------- =/= 022
I = 9 Element at i = 100
I = 10 Element at i = 101
I = 11 Element at i = 102
I = 12 Element at i = 110
I = 13 Element at i = 111
I = 14 Element at i = 112
I = 15 Element at i = 120
I = 16 Element at i = 121
I = 17 Element at i = 122
I = 18 Element at i = 200
I = 19 Element at i = 201
I = 20 Element at i = 202
I = 21 Element at i = 210
I = 22 Element at i = 211
I = 23 Element at i = 212
I = 24 Element at i = 220
I = 25 Element at i = 221
I = 26 Element at i = 222
```

This seems rather elementary to me, yet I'm not sure what I'm missing at this point. The majority of the loop prints out right, yet it's this part in the middle that's not outputting correctly, and searches on multidimensional array issues haven't yielded much in the way of solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because `0*` (0 prefix) is used to store **octal** numbers (base8)

```
            {000, 001, 002}, //0,1,2 
            {010, 011, 012}, //8,9,10 
            {020, 021, 022}, //16,17,18
```

That swhy 010 translates to 8 decimal, 11 to 9 etc etc. Just like `0x*`is used to store hexadecimals, aod `***b` to store binaries. `DecimalFormat` gets value of **octal** 010, that equals to 9, and this is what you are getting in the output.

Rest of  the values are decimals, because they do not start with 0. You can prefix every other walue with 0 and see what will happen.